# Pandas equivalent of a SQL not exists subquery

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to remove certain rows from a Pandas table. It is essentially a deduplication exercise:

I have a table

```
           id          sub_id1       sub_id2              date       
0           1           424755           101        2018-09-21      
1           2           424755           101        2018-09-21
2           3           424755           102        2018-09-21
3           4           678321           101        2018-09-21
4           5           678321           102        2018-09-22
5           6           424755           102        2018-09-22
```

I want to remove a row if there is another row that matches the `sub_id1` and `date`, but has a lower `sub_id2`.

The SQL I would write for this would be

```
select * from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table
                  where sub_id1=t.sub_id1
                  and date=t.date
                  and sub_id2<t.sub_id2)
```

Resulting table would be

```
           id          sub_id1       sub_id2              date       
0           1           424755           101        2018-09-21      
1           2           424755           101        2018-09-21
2           4           678321           101        2018-09-21
3           5           678321           102        2018-09-22
4           6           424755           102        2018-09-22
```

Where `id=3` is removed because there are rows that have the exact same `sub_id1` and date column as it does, with a lower `sub_id2`.

Trying to figure this out using Pandas merges. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a `groupby` problem + `min` value slice (I am using `transform` `min` here)

```
s=df.groupby(['sub_id1','date']).sub_id2.transform('min')
df[df.sub_id2==s]
Out[146]: 
   id  sub_id1  sub_id2        date
0   1   424755      101  2018-09-21
1   2   424755      101  2018-09-21
3   4   678321      101  2018-09-21
4   5   678321      102  2018-09-22
5   6   424755      102  2018-09-22
```

`where sub_id1=t.sub_id1 and date=t.date` : `df.groupby(['sub_id1','date'])`

`sub_id2<t.sub_id2` : `df.sub_id2==s`

Answer (score 0):

Overview: This code will group the dataset and find the minium composite key value

```
id=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
sub_id1=[424775,424775,424775,678321,678321,424755]
sub_id2=[101,101,102,101,102,102]
date=['2018-09-21','2018-09-21','2018-09-21','2018-09-21','2018-09-21','2018-09-21']

dict={
    'id':id,
    'sub_id1':sub_id1,
    'sub_id2':sub_id2,
    'date':date
}

df1=pd.DataFrame(dict,index=id)
df1['date']=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1.sort_values(['sub_id1','sub_id2'],inplace=True)
#print(df1.info())
#print(df1.keys)
query=df1[df1['date']=='2018-09-21']
#print(query)
#print(df1)
print(df1.groupby(['sub_id1','date'])['sub_id2'].min())
```